# Book Subdivision in Memoir Table of Contents

Tags: memoir

I am writing something in the memoir class, and I would like to do two things.

1. Include the book subdivision headings in the table of contents
2. Restart part numberings with every book

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT as proposed by daleif, a clean solution with memoir internal commands:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\counterwithin*{part}{book}

\begin{document}

\settocdepth{section}% Here you set the depth of your Table of Contents: chapter, section, subsection etc.
\tableofcontents

\book{First Book}
\part{First Part}

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}

\book{Second Book}
\part{First Part}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Its probably easier to just dominate the part counter, `\numberwithin{part}{book}`, then no patching is needed

Comment: @daleif: oops... Shall I delete / edit my answer?

Comment: Just edit it.  Oops its called `\coutnerwithin*{part}{book}` (the unstarred version redefines `\thepart` which might not be wanted)